# tableview index getting clipped at the bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using uitables with indexes. My index includes A-Z, . and [.

From what I can see, the end of the index (i.e. the letter 'Z') is a little bit clipped at the bottom. However, the start of the index is also a little bit lower than it could be. Any ideas what to do about these ?

Since the index will be auto generated from a list of files (that will change dynamically), is there a way to have A-Z and others (instead of having the 1st letter of every file name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check your xib file in the interface editor as it is likely that your text area or scroll view area are not stretched to the bottom of the screen and are getting cut off.